# Need to know whether a device is wired serial or Bluetooth

Tags: .net, windows, bluetooth

I need to find out programatically whether a connection is a Bluetooth connection rather than a physically wired connection to a comm port.

This is on Windows using .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, difficult, this emulation is done at the device driver level.  You can get some info out of the driver with WMI, Win32_SerialPort class.  Maybe you can key off some of this.  Try it out with the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) utility, it also generates the code you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, something like I describe in 32feet.NET's [User Guide](http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/32feet.NET%20--%20User%20Guide.html):

> - Getting virtual COM port names for remote Bluetooth devices
>
> On Win32, to find which virtual COM port is for which remote device use WMI to query the serial ports; the remote device address is included in the PnP Id.  In the following PowerShell example see the remote address as “00803A686519”.
>
> ```
> C:\> Get-WmiObject -query "select DeviceID,PNPDeviceID from Win32_SerialPort"
> DeviceID     : COM66 
> PNPDeviceID  : BTHENUM\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}\7&1D80ECD3&0&00803A686519_C00000003
> … …
> ```