# Getting the Port for a USB device

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, port

I just ported some code over from xp to windows 8.1. My code when running on xp could detect the usb device and determine the com port. It seems that this has changed in windows 8.1.

To obtain the com port in xp, I would I have the following method:

```
private void SetComPort()
{

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSSerial_PortName");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Detected PortName: {0}", queryObj["PortName"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Driver Name: {0}", queryObj["InstanceName"]);

        if (queryObj["InstanceName"].ToString().Contains(_driver))
        {

            _comPort = queryObj["PortName"].ToString();
        }

        if (queryObj["InstanceName"].ToString().Contains("USB") || queryObj["InstanceName"].ToString().Contains(_driver))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(queryObj["PortName"] + " is a USB to SERIAL adapter/converter");
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code in 8.1 `searcher.Get()` returns 0 objects. So I searched and found the following code which will list all the devices, but not the com port:

```
private List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
{
        List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\cimv2", @"Select * From Win32_USBHub");

        foreach (var device in searcher.Get())
        {
            devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
            (String)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
            (String)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
            (String)device.GetPropertyValue("Description"),
            (String)device.GetPropertyValue("Name")
            ));
        }

        return devices;

}
```

How can I determine the port by DeviceID?

Comment: MSSerial_PortName is not documented.  Use the documented [Win32_SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991517/how-do-i-get-serial-port-device-id

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for helping. Unfortunately `Win32_SerialPort` does not tell me the com port of the device.

Comment: It does, DeviceID property.  SerialPort.PortName is a string as well of course, serial port devices have names, not numbers.  It is going to be something like "COM66", if you absolutely need a number then you can of course parse it out of the string.  Play with the [WMI Code Creator utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to discover these things by yourself.

Comment: I understand the port number is a string e.g. COM3. Nevertheless, `"SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort` returns zero (0) entries. but `Select * From Win32_USBHub` does return the deviceId. With the deviceId, can I determine the port number?