# Get the string with parent of device

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows

In device manager of windows7 in com port's branch I choose menu "properties" one of port. In tab of "details" I chose property "parent" and see the string:

[image]

How I can obtain this string from vb .net or another language in visual studio in cmd also will be good?

I tried to use win32_ clases: pnpentity, serialPort etc but this no solved to my problem even output of Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort in PS had not property "parent".

```
 Dim objService = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

        For Each objPort In objService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid='{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}'")

            Console.WriteLine(objPort.Caption & vbCrLf)

            Console.Write(objPort.DeviceID & vbCrLf)
            Console.ReadLine()

        Next
```

Except Device ID I try Caption and all syntax that available in [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
Do you have any idea, please?

Comment: which language are you wrigint in C# or Vb? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19826972/579895) helps you

Comment: I use Vb, but it does not matter, because I sure that in my case solution on c# will be similar. Did you read my text? I wrote that i use Win32_SerialPort  and etc for a trying to obtaind parent of device. See the Code in main message.

Comment: Pikoh, thank you! I will try to use this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was the following:

1. Get all active ports with their PnpDeviceIds:

   ```
   private static List<PortInfo> GetActivePorts()
   {
       var ports = new List<PortInfo>();

       using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort"))
       using (var collection = searcher.Get())
       {
           foreach (var device in collection)
           {
               var portInfo = new PortInfo
               {
                   Port = (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
                   PnPDeviceId = (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID")
               };
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(portInfo.Port) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(portInfo.PnPDeviceId))
               {
                   ports.Add(portInfo);
               }
           }
       }

       return ports;
   }
   ```

where PortInfo is

```
    private class PortInfo
    {
        public string Port { get; set; }
        public string PnPDeviceId { get; set; }
        public string ParentDeviceId { get; set; }
    }
```

2. fill ParentDeviceIds :

   ```
   private static async void FillParentIds(IReadOnlyCollection<PortInfo> ports)
   {
       var propertiesToQuery = new List<string> {
           "System.Devices.DeviceInstanceId",
           "System.Devices.Parent"
       };

       var aqs = string.Join(" OR ", ports.Select(p => $"System.Devices.DeviceInstanceId:={p.PnPDeviceId}"));
       var pnpDevices = await PnpObject.FindAllAsync(PnpObjectType.Device, propertiesToQuery, aqs);
       foreach (var pnpDevice in pnpDevices)
       {
           var port = ports.FirstOrDefault(p => string.Compare(p.PnPDeviceId, pnpDevice.Id, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);
           if (port != null && pnpDevice.Properties.TryGetValue("System.Devices.Parent", out var parentId))
           {
               port.ParentDeviceId = parentId?.ToString();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

ParentDeviceId will be that string you are looking for.

Comment: Mihass, many thanks for the response. I'll try it as soon as possible and share result with you.

Comment: where is Windows.Devices.Enumeration.pnp.dll , Is there any alternative solution to create PnpObject?

Comment: you could find it in Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd which is a part of Windows 10 SDK (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)